# Excel Formula to count arguments in a sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been given a spreadsheet with a series of values in a column, made from summing individual numbers. e.g. `=1+2+3`

I'm looking for a way to count the number of numbers that have been summed (i.e. 3)?

But I can't seem to find any Excel formulas which will run on other formulas. Anything like LEN just runs on the result, not the formula.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the formulas are like your example then you can use `FORMULATEXT` function like this

`=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A2),"+",""))+1`

That counts the number of "+"s in your formula and adds 1 which should be the count of numbers added

`FORMULATEXT` function is available in Excel `2013` and later versions